# Replace URLs in text with HTML links, UNLESS already link

Tags: regex, replace, hyperlink

I am trying to replace URLs in text by an actual HTML URL... **UNLESS** it's already an HTML URL. I am working on resigning a forum that allowed users to enter HTML, so savvy users have already typed in full URL...

So this should get replaced.
`I have found this cool link: http://www.cool-link.com`

But this one should be left alone:
`I have found this cool link: <a href="http://www.cool-link.com">http://www.cool-link.com</a>`

So is there a way to replace "http://..." by a hyperlink, UNLESS said URL is preceded by `href="` or in between `<` and `>`.

EDIT: The various solutions I found online (including on stackoverflow) would replace both of the above, and I cannot for the life of me change the pattern to meet my needs.

Cheers :)

Alix

Answer (score 0):

The following regex should do it:

```
/(?<!(href=\")|(\>))(https?:\/\/.+\b)/gi
```

See it working here: https://regexr.com/4hnns